# Syntax error - typescript - unexpected token :?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular, and as you know to be a good Angular developer you have to be good in typescript, so I wrote my simple program as you can see :

```
function loge(messag){
    console.log(messag);
}

var message:string;

message = "Hi";

loge(message);
```

There is no Syntax error I believe But I get this in my Terminal :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
  at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
  at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I don't know why I get this, I need to help so I can move on.
I am using the version 2.5.3 of typescript and PhpStrom as an IDE.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use this.loge(message) while calling a function

Comment: And you're actually compiling this into Javascript using `tsc`? Or you're running that Typescript as plain Javascript?

Comment: @Hrishikesh I don't see how that would help here.

Comment: Deceze : Yes I believe so, I am using this : tsc main.ts, But I am getting the same error, at line 5, the unexpected token is ':' ,I dont know the problem because I am sure the code is fine .

Comment: What is your tsconfig.json looking like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type annotations don't exist in JavaScript, so this line:

```
var message:string;
```

Should be:

```
var message
```

Remember to transpile your TypeScript to JavaScript - and reference the JavaScript file in your application.

Comment: Why would I make this change, I am writing a typescript code not javascript, Of course by declaring var message everything will be fine but what is the purpose ? Thank you Sir for your time.

Comment: @TaoufiqBenallah - in the _JavaScript_ file, the type annotation should not be there. In your _TypeScript_ file it should. See the last sentence, you are either not transpiling your code, or your are referencing `app.ts` when you should be referencing the compiled file `app.js`.

Comment: Yes! Now I understand .. Thank you Sir !

Answer (score 7):

I also was getting the same problem because I was trying to compile the .ts file and then trying to run the same .ts file using node file_name.ts command.

But it should be like first compile .ts file using tsc file_name.ts
then run the generated js file using node file_name.js.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The problem is that I was trying to run the .ts file with node, which is actually a JS interpreter, so that gave me the error. the sequence of steps is to first call the TS compiler, and then node. tsc file.ts then node file.js

Answer (score 1):

First you need to **transpile** your typescript into javascript. Then you are able to use them in your browser environment.

Put a tsconfig.json like below into your project folder

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module": "ES6",
      "target": "ES6",
      "baseUrl": "./src/"
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Put your typescript file into `./src` and run `tsc`. Then the **transpiled** file will be in `./dist`. Use them in your browser will work

Comment: Alternately, you can compile using `tsc filename.ts` and then run the transpiled code using `node filename.js`

Answer (score 0):

you should run the JS file not TS file
using:

1. `npx node dist/file_name.js` or
2. `node dist/file_name.js`

Generate the JS file by running `npx tsc -w` or `tsc -w` 
`-w` means watch to make changes in JS file if you make changes in TS file